# Vue multiple api includes

Tags: api, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

Hello I'm trying to display google map and I also have input field. But when I run the code I get this: ***You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page***

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueGmaps from 'vue-gmaps'

import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';


Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
      key: 'AIzaSyCetTFERhTQZDUT1C7GNvElGdsfpVZ98lQ',
       libraries:['places'],
        version:'3'
        // libraries: 'places', //// If you need to use place input
    }
});

Vue.use(VueGmaps, {
  key:'AIzaSyCetTFERhTQZDUT1C7GNvElGdsfpVZ98lQ',
  libraries: ['places'],
  version: '3',

})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that error because the `google map api` is loaded `twice` NOT because you have used `Vue.use()` twice. A possible solution will be to prevent the loading of the `google map api` in the second `Vue.use()` statement by adding the option `loadGoogleApi: 'false'` is stated in [vue-gmaps readme.md](https://github.com/Ridermansb/vue-gmaps)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueGmaps from 'vue-gmaps'

import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';


Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
      key: 'AIzaSyCetTFERhTQZDUT1C7GNvElGdsfpVZ98lQ',
       libraries:['places'],
        version:'3'
        // libraries: 'places', //// If you need to use place input
    }
});

Vue.use(VueGmaps, {
  key:'AIzaSyCetTFERhTQZDUT1C7GNvElGdsfpVZ98lQ',
  libraries: ['places'],
  version: '3',
  loadGoogleApi: 'false',

})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: Why would you call `Vue.use` twice though? That seems repetitive & unnecessary.

Comment: It's not the same package. Those are two different packages from different providers. the only similarity between them is that they both use the `google map api`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps)` is the same in both places, you are duplicating that code. Try calling it just once - you don't need to call it twice just to use the code in two components.